# Написание MMORPG. OpenGl или DirectX?

Tags: directx, c++, opengl

Хочу написать свою игру в жанре MMORPG (скорее всего 3d). Писать на С/С++ и Assembler. Подскажите что лучше для этого использовать - DirectX или OpenGL?

Comment: мой тебе совет : забудь эту бредовую идею... максимум ММО (многопользовательская) : шашки шахматы крестики-нолики сколько угодно, а вот РПГ не добавляй... это не посилам даже многим командам инди разработчиков не говоря уже про одного человека.


Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL. По крайней мере, так портирование игры на другие платформы будет проще.
С другой стороны, никто не мешает сделать в игре несколько модулей, каждый из которых будет использовать какой-то определенный способ отображения. Так, например, сделано в Unreal Tournament. Там три возможных интерфейса: DirectX, OpenGL и Glide. Сейчас последний уже вряд ли актуален.

Answer (score 4):

Рекомендую попробовать и то, и другое. Но по следующему плану. Выберите себе простую задачу (например, нарисовать объемного человечка по старой считалке - "палка, палка, огуречик")  - и попробуйте решить ее самостоятельно (без привлечение форумов, только пользуясь поисковиком) за неделю на каждом языке. Через две недели ответ будет понятен.

Answer (score 2):

тут уже несколько раз сказали, и присоединяюсь:) в одиночку написать серьезную ММОРПГ, особенно перечисленными вами средствами, практически нереально. Во-первых С++/ассемблер - довольно сердитые средства разработки - на них игры пишутся относительно долго (то же касается ДХ - люди тратят годы жизни, чтобы профессионально писать на нем. С ОГЛ ситуация чуть получше). И, если у вас опыт С++ меньше 2-3 лет, багов понаделаете столько, что половину времени будете их чинить.

Был интересный опыт разработки одной нестандартной ММОРПГ(?): [minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/). Насколько знаю, ядро игры было написано одним человеком в короткие сроки на java. Со схематичной графикой. Т.е., в принципе соорудить что-то можно..
Но следует правильно подбирать инструменты, особенно когда вы работаете самостоятельно.

Comment: Minecraft не MMORPG, это жанр Indy и мультиплеер там еще не допилен до нормального состояния

Comment: Ну, во всяком случае это пример проекта с достаточно сложным функционалом и каким-то мультиплеером, написанного умеренными усилиями в умеренные сроки:)

Answer (score 1):

Есть прекрасная книга по этой теме, в ней разбирается всё с нуля - от создания простого окна до построения движка именно в жанре РПГ. Книга называется "ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЕ 
РОЛЕВЫХ ИГР С DirectX", автор Джим Адамс. Есть и на русском и на английском и легко можно найти и скачать в интернете (я скачал, кажется на www.progbook.ru, поэтому и советую). Написать такую игру вполне по силам и одиночке, всё зависит от вашего старания и усидчивости. Вот купит ли у вас её кто-нибудь, вопрос другой, но если просто для себя в качестве опыта, то лучшей книги вы не найдёте.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал тебе OpenGL он не хуже DirectX, а изучать его намного быстрее и легче,
но что касается DirectX то его преимущество в том что он более высокоуровневый, в нем есть функции загрузки 3д объектов, текстур. Функции для работы с матрицами, векторами, и прочей математикой. Да и кроме Direct3d есть еще DirectInput(для обработки ввода с мыши,клавиатуры), DirectMusic, DirectSound(для вывода звука), DirectPlay(для работы с сетью). Так что смотри сам что тебе больше подходит. И еще хочу посоветовать не берись сразу за MMORPG (темболее если нету знаний в разработке игр), начни с аркады или чего нибудь попроще.

Answer (score -3):

Считаю OpenGL морально устаревшим решением. Если есть возможность - DirectX и точка.

Comment: тогда обьясните почему Microsoft использует именно OpenGl для проприсовки GUI OS? а ведь они являются разработчиками DirectX

Comment: Ну как бы гуй и MMORPG немножко разные вещи, логично?

Comment: @jmu, это вообще не в тему.

@Izengardjke, Вы еще XNA и monoxna вспомните, который ни то, ни се и является, по-видимому, единственным способом писать игры под .NET.

Comment: (а)да думаю сложность у гуи пожалуй попроще будет. с другой стороны ежу понятно что производительность там имеет более высокий приоритет (б).   
думаю более важным является (б) а не (а).